# Textbox url string not recognized at remote server in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to query a remote server to see if a file exists or download it. Whichever works. I have no problem doing this at all in VB.Net but being new to `C#`.

I don't know why I get a 404 not found error.

```
   string str = UsernameBox.Text + ".txt";
   string url = "http://mysite.us/Users/" + str;
   WebClient myClient= new WebClient();
   myClient.DownloadFile(url, str);
```

If I type in the name of the file using quotes in my code it works but not when I use a variable and grab a textbox string. Not sure if there I need to reinstall VS 2015. here's a code example above though I've tried several different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem finally. When I was grabbing text from a textbox the end of the text had a line return at the end of it (r/n/) that I couldn't see but it kept being added to the end of the string variable. I needed to repair my VS 2015 installation also because when it would break on that line it wasn't showing the extra characters previously. I hope someone else having the same problem finds this.Thanks anyway.